# Using Qt with Qt creator and visual studio on Windows 7: How to deploy for Windows 8

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2012, qt-creator, qmake

I am using using Qt 5.1.1 with Qt creator 2.8.1 and visual studio 2012 on Windows 7. Creating targets (*.exe files) and exchanging these targets between PCs running with Windows 7 is no problem. However, if I try to run these executables under Windows 8 they crash at startup (Eror code 0xc000007b). I think I have to compile my application for windows 8.

Is there any possibility to do this with my current setup? How do I add a target for Windows 8?

Comment: Have you checked with dependency walker if there is any dll missing?

Comment: Is this resolved now?

Comment: It is now resolved. The problem was not Qt related. A *.dll from another library was missing.

Comment: Which is what I wrote in my initial comment to check with dependency walker. Anyway, which dll was missing, etc? Currently, your question is not useful for others that much without mentioning the exact solution.

Comment: A *.dll that was not Qt related so I was searching completely wrong. The problem was not related to Qt at all.

Comment: But what was it related to?

Comment: A postgres database *.dll that was needed by the application that used Qt

Comment: Right, so as I mentioned "It is possible as the first link writes that you have not deployed all the necessary dlls for your application.". What is missing from the answer still then?

Comment: Is this still unresolved one year later??

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably somewhere else.

For instance, QtCreator is built on Windows 7, and no one has reported any issues on Windows 8 so far.

You would just use the usual spec files that fit your toolchain setup, e.g. `win32-msvc2012`.

Here you can find a screenshot on my PC where this could be configured.

[image]

But really, that is pretty much about it. For solving the real problem, please take a look at the following threads below. It is possible as the first link writes that you have not deployed all the necessary dlls for your application.

[How to solve error message "The application was unable to start correctly (0x000007b). Click OK to close the application"](http://www.bitdefender.com/support/how-to-solve-error-message-%D0%91%E2%94%80%C2%B0the-application-was-unable-to-start-correctly-%280x000007b%29-click-ok-to-close-the-application%D0%91%E2%94%80%C2%B2-1106.html)

[Problem with 0xc000007b Error?](http://www.error-repair-tools.com/ppc/error.php?t=0xc000007b)